# Java Regex Match Word Exclusions

Tags: java, regex

I can't seem to get a regular expression working in Java:

```
String wordExclusion = "(^|\\s)(\\-[^\\s]+(\\s|$))+";
return query.matches(wordExclusion);
```

I expect to match against the following queries:

1. lion -jaguar
2. -jaguar lion
3. ice-cream -chocolate

And not these queries:

1. ice-cream

Comment: So what is the actual reason for a string to get matched? examples are good, but not enough (switch-case behaviour ;))

Comment: I'm assuming you want a regex where a `-` is not immediately preceded by a word character.

Comment: Your regex already doesn't match `ice-cream`

Comment: `matches` only returns true if the entire string is described by the regex.  You probably want to use `find`.

Comment: (1) `-` outside of character class is not metacharacter so you don't need to escape it, (2) `[^\\s]` can be easier represented as `\\S` (capital S), (3) it seems that Affe solved your problem - use `Matcher#find` instead of `String#matches` if you want to check if string *contains* part which could be matched by regex, `String#matches` checks if regex matches *entire String*.

Comment: it's OK! see http://regex101.com/r/hG3bO1/2